# Clean way to return ActiveRecord object with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I want to return all the Thing model objects with just the associations without the `asscoiation_id`, is there a better way to do this without `include` and `except`?

```
# Thing.rb

belongs_to :object_a
belongs_to :object_b
```

```
# create_thing.rb

def change
  create_table :things, id: false do |t|
    t.string :id, limit: 36, primary_key: true
    t.string :object_a_id, foreign_key: true
    t.string :object_b_id, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

```
# things_controller.rb

render json: Thing.all, include: [:object_a, :object_b]

output => {
  id: ....
  object_a_id: 'object_a_id',
  object_b_id: 'object_b_id',
  object_a: {
    id: object_a_id
    ...
  },
  object_b: {
    id: object_b_id
    ...
  }
```

I know I can do this to get what I want but I wondered if there is a DRY way to do this without all the include and except.

```
render json: Thing.all, include: [:object_a, :object_b], except: [:object_a_id, :object_b_id]

output => {
  id: ....
  object_a: {
    id: object_a_id
    ...
  },
  object_b: {
    id: object_b_id
    ...
  }
```

Comment: The way you suggested at the end is pretty DRY. What feels icky about that to you?

Comment: It would be elegant without include and except both in `render json: Thing.all, include: [:object_a, :object_b], except: [:object_a_id, :object_b_id]` cuz there is going to be a lot of those end point

Comment: I thought I set up the table relationships incorrectly at first because I always thought there is an option to either get the model with the full associated object or just `the association_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

A DRY approach is inside your models, you can define a `attributes` method and have it return the shape of the object that you want the render function to use.

```
# thing.rb

def attributes
  # Return the shape of the object
  # You can use symbols if you like instead of string keys
  {
    'id' => id,                      # id of the current thing
    'other_fields' => other_fields,  # add other fields you want in the serialized result   
    'object_a' => object_a,          # explicitly add the associations
    'object_b' => object_b
  }
end
```

The associations `object_a` and `object_b` should get serialized as normal. You can repeat the same approach for them by adding an `attributes` method in their respective classes if you want to limit/customize their serialized result.

So when `render json:`  is called on a single, or a collection of, thing model(s), the shape of the json objects returned will be as defined in the method above.

#### Note:

One caveat is your key names in the hash being returned in `attributes` has to match the name of the method (or association name). I'm not too sure why. But the workaround that I've used when needing to add a key with a different name than its corresponding column is to make a method in the model of the key name I want to use.

For example, say your `Thing` model has a column `name`, but in your json result you want the key name that corresponds to that column to be called `name_of_thing`. You'd do the following:

```
def name_of_thing
  name
end

def attributes
  {
    'name_of_thing' => name_of_thing,
    # other fields follow
    # ...
  }
end
```

---

### Conditional Logic

#### Conditions dependent on fields/associations in the model

The `attributes` method can support conditional based on fields in the model.

```
# thing.rb

def attributes
  result = {}

  result['id'] = id
  # add other fields

  # For example, if association to object_a exists
  if object_a
    result.merge!({
      'object_a' => object_a
    })
  end

  # return result
  result
end
```

#### Conditions dependent on input from outside the model

If you want to make your method render different fields in different places, one thing you can do is override the `as_json` method, which can work better for these cases because this method accepts options in a parameter.

```
# thing.rb

def as_json(options = {})
  result = {}

  result['id'] = id
  # add other fields to result

  if(options[:show_only_ids])
    result.merge!({
      'object_a_id' => object_a_id,
      'object_b_id' => object_b_id
    })
  else
    result.merge!({
      'object_a' => object_a,
      'object_b' => object_b
    })
  end

  # return result
  result
end
```

Then you need to modify your controller (or wherever you're calling the serialization of the `Thing` model) to pass in the appropriate option when necessary.

```
# thing_controller.rb

render json: Thing.all.as_json({ show_only_ids: true })
```

When rendering, you don't always have to explicitly specify the `as_json`. The render function will call it anyway by default. You only need to explicitly make that call when you want to pass in options.

Comment: That seems to work. I guess this is some Rails magic again. Do you have a link in a Rails doc where it talks about this or knows what to call this? I am going to have to explain this

Comment: is there a way to control this behavior? so we have an endpoint `/things` where we want just the `association_ids` and `/thing-details` where we want the full association objects.

Comment: For documentation, what you're looking for is the serializable_hash functionality: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Comment: For the controlling of this behavior, I've added some conditional logic to the attributes method before with no issues, but it was all determined by data in the model itself, not a controller. The approach you might want to take is overriding `as_json` in your model because that can take options. Then you can use conditional logic based on the parameter you pass. I'll update my answer to show you how. https://rubyinrails.com/2019/07/15/override-as-json-rails/

Comment: No probs! If it's not too much trouble, could you accept the answer? Thank you!

Comment: Heads up. you might want to update ur answer with `merge!`